Permutation of a set that gives multiple of 2010
This problem is from the 2010 USAJMO I couldn't solve it and the solutions are quite hard to understand:

A permutation of the set of positive integers $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is a sequence $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ such that each element of $[n]$ appears precisely one time as a term of the sequence. For example, $(3, 5, 1, 2, 4)$ is a permutation of $[5]$. Let $P(n)$ be the number of permutations of $[n]$ for which $ka_k$ is a perfect square for all $1\leq k\leq n$. Find with proof the smallest $n$ such that $P(n)$ is a multiple of $2010$.

What I tried: I looked at smaller cases, $P(1), P(2), P(3)...$ I found that each time P(n), n is a perfect square, the number of permutations increases, where the perfect squares can be put in any perfect square position, i.e. $a_1$, $a_4$, $a_9$ and will result in a perfect square as a perfect square multiplied by another will result in a perfect square. I got $P(1)$ to $P(3)$ $=1$, $P(4)$ to $P(7)$ $=2$ $P(8)=4$, $P(9)$ to $P(11)$ $=12$, $P(12)$ to $P(15)$ $=24$, $P(16)=96$ (don't even know if they are correct, please check for me) and this creates a problem for me.
The problem I face was that this would create a predictable pattern which maybe could be generalised, i.e. P(n)=(number of squares from 1 to n)!, but there are other numbers that can be permuted with each other as well, for example $2,8$ can be swapped as $2*8=4^2$ and similarly with $3,12$, etc. I don't know how to make progress further or maybe my path is completely wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Can you give the 2 permutations you got for say, $P(3)$?

oh wait thats a mistake, P(1) to P(3) is 1, P(4) to P(7) is 2

$ka_k$ is a square iff the squarefree part of $k$ is equal to the squarefree part of $a_k$. Thus one can freely permute all numbers with the same square-free part, and only those.
For example, to compute $P(18)$, we can take any permutation of $1,4,9,16$ (the squares), as well as of $2,8,18$ (squarefree part $2$), and may swap $3$ and $12$ (squarefree part $3$), while everything else has to stay fixed, for a total of $4!\cdot3!\cdot2!=288$ options.
In general, there are $\left\lfloor\sqrt\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$ numbers with squarefree part $k$ that are at most $n$, so $$P(n)=\prod_{k\text{ squarefree}}\left\lfloor\sqrt\frac nk\right\rfloor!$$

Now we can find the smallest $n$ such that $2010\mid P(n)$. Note $2010=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot67$, and the only way to get a $67$ in a product of factorials is if the argument of one of the factorials is $\geq 67$. This happens first with the $k=1$ factor, hence the solution is $n=67^2$.

What's a square free part? Is it just the numbers that are one part away from being a square like 2,8,18 just needs one more 2 to be a square? Also how'd you derive the formula? Everything else I understand

You can think about it in terms of an equivalence relation: $a \sim b$ if and only if $ab$ is a perfect square. You can show it's an equivalence relation, and ${2, 8, 18, \ldots, 2k^2, \ldots, n}$ would be one such equivalence class. The square-free part of the number would be the least element of the equivalence class (i.e. $2$ in that case).

Squarefree means not divisible by any square (other than $1$). Every integer can be uniquely written in the form $kn^2$ with $k$ squarefree, which is called the squarefree part.

ok I understand square free and parts now. But how does the formula work, like how is it derived, I don't understand

I really don't know what else to say. Do you understand the example? For each $k$, we can permute the numbers with squarefree part $k$, of which there are $\lfloor\sqrt\frac nk\rfloor$ (solve $kx^2\leq n$), hence that gives $\lfloor\sqrt\frac nk\rfloor!$ possibilities. We can do that for all $k$ independently, so multiply all of them for the total count.
